# How do I get Qt SDK configured properly with Yocto project?

Tags: qt, embedded, yocto

I'm new to Yocto Project. The initial idea is to create a custom image based on `core-image-full-cmdline` (this is with no windowing system) and [generate](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-building-an-sdk-installer) a Qt5 SDK against this image.

- <strike>So my target to be able to run Qt applications needs to have some
  headers & libraries installed, isn't ? What I must specify on my image recipe ?</strike>
- Doing `$ bitbake my_image -c populate_sdk` will generate `my_image` with Qt5 support + SDK installer ?

As I understood, to get a Qt SDK the steps would be:

1. Download and add `meta-qt5` to bblayers.conf.
2. Add to the image recipe against which you want to build the SDK:
   `inherit populate_sdk_qt5`
3. Configure the SDK build (add/remove features). <- Here I need help. I only want `EGLFS` support, no X11/Wayland and no Qtwebkit (and idk, maybe some other features that I'm not aware yet).
4. `bitbake my_image -c populate_sdk`

My build got an error compiling wayland although I have this:
`DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"`

Comment: populate-sdk will generate a script that will install all parts, Qmake, Qt libs and headers for your target architecture.

Comment: @LPs So I don't need to do nothing more apart of adding meta-qt5 to bblaers.conf?

Comment: Adding to bblayers.conf make `Bitbake` able to see all recipes into `Qt5` layer. You have to add required packets int your recipe or into local.conf, like: `qtbase`, `qt3d`, `qtserial`, etc... Then add `inherit populate_sdk_qt5` to your recipe to make `Yocto` able to install all components of Qt5 into SDK.

Comment: @LPs Would u mind to explain further or  point me to some documentation where it's explained? I mean I want to understand what `populate_sdk_qt5` does and I want to be able to configure the process. My build failed. I need to disable some features because I don't need X11/Wayland neither qtwebkit. Btw, referring to my 1st point, I discovered that Qt application can be deployed on targets without Qt libs installed on but I can bundle them so for now I won't install qt packages. I only need to get the SDK.

Comment: If your recipe is working (Bitbake can deplay the full recipe) populate SDK extract from the "compiled" recipe all files needed for SDK: cross compiler, cross-linker, libs, interfaces (.h) and so on. So if you want an SDK for your target architecture, with Yocto, you must have a working recipe.

Comment: @LPs yes, my image recipe works, I first did successful build  `bitbake my_image`. It fails when I populate_sdk

Comment: You should post a new question with error details. BTW populate_sdk recipes needs more packages, like _dev (developement) an some other download that can conflict with something into your recipe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made some mistakes. So these are the steps:

1. Download and add `meta-qt5` to bblayers.conf.
2. Add to the image recipe against which you want to build the SDK: `inherit populate_sdk_qt5`. Now the do_populate_sdk task knows the target and will install the needed headers and libs on the respective sysroot (which will be needed later to be able to configure QtCreator per example)

   2.1 As we gonna generate an SDK, dev packages are needed. Add this to the image recipe: `IMAGE_FEATURES += "dev-pkgs"`

   2.2 If our distro doesn't have any windows manager: `DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"`. My mistake was to put this on my image recipe but it must be set on `local.conf` so all the recipes are aware of this. [More info about Qt backends](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html)

   2.3 I'm not sure about this but I wanted to remove qtwebkit, and I added (on local.conf): `PACKAGECONFIG_remove_pn-qttools = "qtwebkit"`
   `PACKAGECONFIG_remove_pn-qtquick1 = "qtwebkit"`. Still qtwebkit module is built. I need to investigate more about this.
3. Build the image `$ bitbake my_image`
4. Build the SDK `$ bitbake my_image -c populate_sdk`

Now we got a toolchain needed for cross-compile.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add Qt5 to your image-based SDK, you need to add the following line to your image recipe:

```
inherit populate_sdk_qt5
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want default `Qt5 SDK` use
   `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` or
2. If you need Qt5 sdk with extra packages then first compile your qt5 image with required packages after that compile sdk.

   `bitbake custom-qt5-image`

   `bitbake -c do_populate_sdk  custom-qt5-image`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path of meta-qt5 in your conf/bblayers.conf to the BBLAYERS variable.
I think it's all you need to start.

Comment: I already did that. So when I build, bitbake already "knows" that the SDK that I want is from meta-qt5?

Answer (score 0):

Use Default Qt5 SDK for default Qt5 packages: 
Follow this steps in below link
[Yocto Qt5 Toolchain Installation](http://www.variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Qt5_Toolchain_installation)

Or `inherit populate_sdk populate_sdk_qt5`
and `IMAGE_FEATURES += "other packages"` in your-custom-image.bb

```
bitbake your-custom-image -c populate_sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove qtwebkit , you need to adjust this package

meta-qt5/recipes-qt/packagegroups/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bb

```
RDEPENDS_${PN}_remove = " \
    qtwebkit-dev \
    qtwebkit-mkspecs \
    qtwebkit-qmlplugins \
"
```

then

```
bitbake your-custom-image -c populate_sdk
```

Comment: To clarify, don't modify the recipe directly, add a `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bbappend` to you own meta layer and add the `RDEPENDS_${PN}_remove` line.