# How do I generate a toolchain for Windows using Yocto?

Tags: windows, qt, sdk, yocto

[On my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258161/how-do-i-get-qt-sdk-configured-properly-with-yocto-project) I asked how to get a Qt toolchain. I tried on Linux host and it works. Now I need to know how to make work that toolchain on Windows platform? Or what Yocto setup do I need to generate a Qt Windows SDK installer?

Would `SDK_OS = "Windows"` do anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't so hard.
Just need to download and add the layer `meta-mingw` and set `SDKMACHINE` to a machine available (basically 32b or 64b) on `meta-mingw/conf/machine-sdk`