# Can't generate SDK for Windows with Yocto

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, yocto, toolchain

I've build a Linux image for freescale imx6qpsabreai board and SDK with toolchain which works well on Linux.

Now I want to support development on Windows and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376459/how-do-i-generate-a-toolchain-for-windows-using-yocto) post I've

- downloaded [oe meta-mingw](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-mingw/) into *sources/meta-openembedded/meta-mingw*
- added SDKMACHINE=x86_64-mingw32 to local.conf in my project

however, I can't build new SDK this way.

```
~/yocto/fsl-community-bsp/build_fsl_framebuffer$ bitbake fsl-image-machine-test -c populate_sdk
Loading cache: 100% |###############################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 2 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: /home/slavskaya/yocto/fsl-community-bsp/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-mingw/recipes-support/libiconv/libiconv_1.14.bb: Error executing a python function in <code>:                        | ETA:  --:--:--

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: '<code>', lineno: 13, function: <module>
     0009:__anon_35__home_slavskaya_yocto_fsl_community_bsp_sources_poky_meta_classes_devshell_bbclass(d)
     0010:__anon_106__home_slavskaya_yocto_fsl_community_bsp_sources_poky_meta_classes_sstate_bbclass(d)
     0011:__anon_45__home_slavskaya_yocto_fsl_community_bsp_sources_poky_meta_classes_blacklist_bbclass(d)
     0012:__anon_158__home_slavskaya_yocto_fsl_community_bsp_sources_poky_meta_classes_siteinfo_bbclass(d)
 *** 0013:__anon_31__home_slavskaya_yocto_fsl_community_bsp_sources_meta_openembedded_meta_mingw_recipes_support_libiconv_libiconv_1_14_bb(d)
File: '/home/slavskaya/yocto/fsl-community-bsp/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-mingw/recipes-support/libiconv/libiconv_1.14.bb', lineno: 28, function: __anon_31__home_slavskaya_yocto_fsl_community_bsp_sources_meta_openembedded_meta_mingw_recipes_support_libiconv_libiconv_1_14_bb
     0024:inherit autotools pkgconfig gettext
     0025:
     0026:python __anonymous() {
     0027:    if d.getVar("TARGET_OS") != "linux":
 *** 0028:        return
     0029:    if d.getVar("TCLIBC") == "glibc":
     0030:        raise bb.parse.SkipPackage("libiconv is provided for use with uClibc only - glibc already provides iconv")
     0031:}
     0032:
Exception: TypeError: getVar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expand'

ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: /home/slavskaya/yocto/fsl-community-bsp/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-mingw/recipes-support/libiconv/libiconv_1.14.bb

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Also, I am not an experienced C/C++ programmer, but from my point of view mingw doesn't contain compiler for arm architecture, so maybe I just can't get arm toolchain to use on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

meta-mingw builds a cross compile from Linux to Windows (mingw).  It then uses this cross compiler to construct a standard toolchain from (mingw) to the target SDK environment.  You are using the correct layer, but have a different problem.

It appears that you are using a layer (meta-mingw) that is expecting the newer bitbake semantics:

```
 0027:    if d.getVar("TARGET_OS") != "linux":
```

*** 0028:        return
Exception: TypeError: getVar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expand'

Bitbake used to require two arguments to 'd.getVar', and now only requires one (the second is optional).

I would suggest that you identify which version of oe-core/poky you are using and get a matching version of meta-mingw.  (It may be as simple as checking out the correct branch.)

Comment: Thank you so much for interpreting this error message, I checked out meta-mingw master branch while using morty yocto branch.