# Unable to build Windows toolchain from Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am attempting to build a Windows toolchain from Yocto (running on Linux) so that we can use a different build system to build applications for our embedded device.  Yocto is running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I looked at [Can't generate SDK for Windows with Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098497/cant-generate-sdk-for-windows-with-yocto) and [How do I generate a toolchain for Windows using Yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376459/how-do-i-generate-a-toolchain-for-windows-using-yocto) and have added meta-mingw to my Yocto work directory; I am running Yocto Zeus, so I cloned it with command `git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-mingw -b zeus` and added it to my bblayers.conf file.  I also added `SDK_ARCH = "x86_64"` to my local.conf

I am building the toolchain by running `bitbake meta-toolchain`.  I am trying to build a set of 64 bit binaries (we have had out of memory issues with our existing 32-bit Linaro toolchain).

I am seeing the install script as you would expect in `/home/gen-ccm-root/workdir/tools/poky/build-dev/tmp/deploy/sdk` but all the binaries it built were Linux ELF files.  What step am I missing?  I didn't see how to do this in the Yocto SDK manual (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html)  Is there a different document I should be looking at?

A couple of other things I have tried:

Changing SDK_ARCH in my local.conf to `SDK_ARCH = "x86_64-mingw64"` which didn't rebuild anything (after I built the Linux toolchain above)

Adding `#SDKMACHINE ?= "x86_64-mingw64"` to the local.conf

I tried mingw32 as well since that is what is in the layer conf.

Comment: You probably have different layers checked out at different Yocto releases. All layers in use should be checked out at their zeus branch or a branch that advertises zeus support (i.e. `zeus` in `conf/layer.conf`'s `LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-xxx`).

Comment: I am not sure how, but some layer somewhere got hosed.  I will edit the question, it now builds, but it isn't building a Windows toolchain, it is building a Linux toolchain, so there is a missing step somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meta-toolchain` doesn't appear to work anymore.

In the end, I added meta-mingw to my bblayers.conf and the following to my local.conf:

```
SDKMACHINE = "x86_64-mingw32"
SDK_ARCHIVE_TYPE = "zip"
```

And, after building building my project, used the following to build the SDK: `bitbake mi-dev -c populate_sdk` where `mi-dev` is my build.