# During SDK build: environment-setup.d/ conflicts between attempted installs

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build an image for beaglebone that contains Qt5, as well as generate the SDK for this image.

## Problem

my problem is, that the build fails the `do_populate_sdk` task to create the SDK with the following error:

> Error: Transaction check error:
>     file /opt/poky/2.3.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/environment-setup.d conflicts between attempted installs of nativesdk-cmake-3.7.2-r0.x86_64_nativesdk and nativesdk-qtbase-tools-5.8.0+git0+49dc9aa409-r0.x86_64_nativesdk

A little further up the stream I encountered the following error message:

> ERROR: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/ubuntu/workspace/bbb/build-toaster-2/tmp/work/my_machine-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf [...] ' returned 1:
>   Added oe-repo repo from file:///home/ubuntu/workspace/bbb/build-toaster-2/tmp/work/my-machine-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-image-dev/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo.
>   Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:00 ago on Wed Aug 16 11:47:27 2017 UTC.
>   Dependencies resolved.

## What I have

To configure my image I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40375372/2865814) as well as similar posts stating the same elsewhere on the web. This is my (shortened and slightly redacted) image bb-file:

```
SUMMARY = "..."
LICENSE = "MIT"

IMAGE_LINGUAS = "en-us"

inherit core-image

# for populate_sdk to create a valid toolchain
inherit populate_sdk populate_sdk_qt5

CORE_OS = "..."
KERNEL_EXTRA_INSTALL = "..."
WIFI_SUPPORT = "..."

DEV_SDK_INSTALL = " \
    binutils \
    binutils-symlinks \
    coreutils \
    cpp \
    cpp-symlinks \
    diffutils \
    file \
    g++ \
    g++-symlinks \
    gdb \
    gdbserver \
    gcc \
    gcc-symlinks \
    gettext \
    git \
    ldd \
    libstdc++ \
    libstdc++-dev \
    libtool \
    make \
    perl-modules \
    pkgconfig \
    python-modules \
    python3-modules \
 "

DEV_EXTRAS = "..."

EXTRA_TOOLS_INSTALL = " \
    acpid \
    bc \
    bzip2 \
    cursor-blink \
    devmem2 \
    dosfstools \
    emmc-installer \
    ethtool \
    findutils \
    i2c-tools \
    iperf3 \
    htop \
    less \
    memtester \
    nano \
    netcat \
    procps \
    rsync \
    sysfsutils \
    tcpdump \
    unzip \
    util-linux \
    util-linux-blkid \
    wget \
    zip \
 "

MQTT = "..."
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "..."

QT_TOOLS = " \
    qtbase \
    qtbase-dev \
    qtbase-mkspecs \
    qtbase-plugins \
    qtbase-tools \
    qtserialport-dev \
    qtserialport-mkspecs \
    qt5-env \
 "

QT5_PKGS = " \
    qt3d \
    qt3d-dev \
    ...
    qtxmlpatterns \
    qtxmlpatterns-dev \
    qtxmlpatterns-mkspecs \
"

FONTS = "..."
TSLIB = "... "
ADDITIONAL_PKGS = "..."
QT_TEST_APPS = "..."

IMAGE_INSTALL += " \
    ${CORE_OS} \
    ${DEV_SDK_INSTALL} \
    ${DEV_EXTRAS} \
    ${EXTRA_TOOLS_INSTALL} \
    ${KERNEL_EXTRA_INSTALL} \
    ${FONTS} \
    ${QT_TOOLS} \
    ${QT5_PKGS} \
    ${QT_TEST_APPS} \
    ${MQTT} \
    ${WIFI_SUPPORT} \
    ${TSLIB} \
    ${ADDITIONAL_PKGS} \
 "

IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " dev-pkgs"

export IMAGE_BASENAME = "my-image-dev"
```

I also set `DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "busybox x11 wayland"` as well as `DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd opengl aufs"` in my `local.conf`.

The build runs fine if I remove the `inherit populate_sdk_qt5` line, but of course I don't get make for my SDK in this case.

## What I found out

I found different people having the same problem (example [here](https://boundarydevices.com/pyro-yocto-release/#comment-378606)) but no-one ever got an answer.

I checked the nativesdk-cmake as well as the nativesdk-qtbase_git recipes (both unchanged standards) to see where the files get created, and neither looks problematic to me:

natives-qtbase_git.bb:

```
fakeroot do_generate_qt_environment_file() {
    mkdir -p ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/
    script=${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/qt5.sh

    echo 'export PATH=${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS}:$PATH' > $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS"' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS"' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_CC=$CC' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_CXX=$CXX' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_LINK=$CXX' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_AR=$AR' >> $script
    echo 'export QT_CONF_PATH=${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS}/qt.conf' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT=`qmake -query QT_INSTALL_LIBS`' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_INCDIR_QT=`qmake -query QT_INSTALL_HEADERS`' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_MOC=${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS}/moc' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_UIC=${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS}/uic' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_RCC=${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS}/rcc' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_QDBUSCPP2XML=${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS}/qdbuscpp2xml' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_QDBUSXML2CPP=${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS}/qdbusxml2cpp' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_QT_CONFIG=`qmake -query QT_INSTALL_LIBS`${QT_DIR_NAME}/mkspecs/qconfig.pri' >> $script
    echo 'export OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS=${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HOST_BINS}' >> $script
    echo 'export QMAKESPEC=`qmake -query QT_INSTALL_LIBS`${QT_DIR_NAME}/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++' >> $script

    # Use relocable sysroot
    sed -i -e 's:${SDKPATHNATIVE}:$OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT:g' $script
}
```

cmake-3.7.2.bb:

```
do_install_append_class-nativesdk() {
    mkdir -p ${D}${datadir}/cmake
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/OEToolchainConfig.cmake ${D}${datadir}/cmake/

    mkdir -p ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/environment.d-cmake.sh ${D}${SDKPATHNATIVE}/environment-setup.d/cmake.sh
}
```

environment.d-cmake.sh:

```
alias cmake="cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake"
```

For the sake of trying I went ahead and executed the
`/home/ubuntu/workspace/bbb/build-toaster-2/tmp/work/my_machine-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf`
script from
`/home/ubuntu/workspace/bbb/build-toaster-2/tmp/work/my_machine-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native`
which got me the following error message:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/bbb/build-toaster-2/tmp/work/my-machine-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf.real", line 57, in <module>  
>     from dnf.cli import main  
> ImportError: No module named 'dnf'
> ```

The dnf module seems to exist though:

```
<path as above>/recipe-sysroot-native$ find -name dnf
./usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dnf
./usr/bin/dnf
./etc/dnf
./etc/bash_completion.d/dnf
./etc/logrotate.d/dnf
```

Can you see anything that I am doing wrong? I am absolutely clueless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm building an SDK  with cmake and Qt5 without any problem...

Your issue seems to stem from `dnf`, and as I'm building with `ipk` without any issue, there might very well be a bug in the `rpm` handling in OpenEmbedded.

Could you try to rebuild with:

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"
```

in your `local.conf` and see it that helps?

Comment: Thanks Anders, this worked perfectly fine. I performed a full rebuild just to be sure and the SDK built without any problem. Are there any possible downsides of choosing idk over rpm?

Answer (score 2):

> *Edit*:
>   Anders' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45883578/2865814) provides a more elegant solution by switching the packaging class. If you can, check out his approach before trying this workaround.

I found a workaround that worked for me but is no ideal solution. I am posting it anyway, in case it helps someone:

I figured out, that the `nativesdk-cmake` package somehow collided with the Qt one. Therefor I created a `nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bbappend` file in my custom layer, with the following content:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN}_remove = "\
    nativesdk-cmake \
"
```

This removes the cmake dependency from the SDK build, which works for my purposes. But this merely solves the symptoms not the problem. So I am glad for any other solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just try and add DIRFILES = "" in nativesdk-qtbase.bb (you should rather set up a clean and tidy nativesdk-qtbase.bbappend in your custom layer with DIRFILES = "").
This works around clashes due to RPM directory ownership for this RPM, which is a default policy in standard RPM packaging. See package_rpm.bbclass for details @ python write_specfile () { .... walk_files method.
Note: DIRFILES must be defined but left empty for this to work on the current package.
Voila.

Cheers.

Comment: This didn't work for me at first, but did work after changing the DIRFILES value from "" to " ", and renaming from `recipes-qt\qt5\nativesdk-qtbase_git.bbappend` to `recipes-qt\qt5\nativesdk-qtbase_%.bbappend` in my image. I'm not sure which change did the trick and will update if I get around to exploring that further.

Answer (score 1):

As so61pi mentioned, RPM has strict checking for files/directories. In my case, after installing nativesdk-qtbase the environment.d folder had permissions 775 whereas nativesk-cmake created that same folder with 755.

I don't know if this was caused due to the fact that the function `generate_qt_environment_file` is being executed in a fakeroot environment, but I fixed it by adding its function body to the `do_install` function and removing `generate_qt_environment_file`.

Not sure if this is the correct fix though. I noticed some other recipes use the fakeroot keyword and others don't. I wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

RPM has strict checking for files/directories. `environment-setup.d` directory in your question may have different mode or user between the 2 packages.

You could check function [rpmfilesCompare](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/db1b99db2543b2c2526a2e116daeffa0498d5de4/lib/rpmfi.c#L910) for the exact checks that RPM performs.