# Bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5: Error do_populate_sdk

Tags: qt5, yocto, bitbake, toolchain, gumstix

Hello everybody,
I try to install the Yocto toolchain with Qt5 to cross-compile code for my Gumstix Overo board on my ubuntu 16.04 virtual machin. 
I successfully passed the first step of build with `bitbake core-image-sato` [there](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixoveror/src/master/YoctoBuildFinalMessageSuccedOvero.txt) but now I need to pass the Qt5 build with `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` and that is my problem. 
That is the error:
`ERROR: meta-toolchain-qt5-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/bschneider/overo/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -y -c /home/bschneider/overo/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/bschneider/overo/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/etc/yum.repos.d --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/bschneider/overo/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo --installroot=/home/bschneider/overo/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image --setopt=logdir=/home/bschneider/overo/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/temp --nogpgcheck install nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host packagegroup-cross-canadian-overo nativesdk-packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-host' returned 1:
Added oe-repo repo from /home/bschneider/overo/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Fri 01 Jun 2018 02:46:23 PM UTC.`
That is the all result:
[bitbucket link](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixoveror/src/master/YoctoQT5BuildFinalMessageError_V2.0.txt)
Someone can please help me to solve this problem. I tried many times to build that but now I have no more idee how to fix it. 
Thanks you.

Comment: http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-devel/2018-April/117915.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to backport this [patch](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/commit/d9001fc53d340544356b2bfb5c7c5f3c7f831319) from upstream meta-qt5

Comment: @Oleksandr Kravchuk, Thank you for your answers ! I am not really sure about that but your both answer say the same thing, right ?
If yes, how can I apply a patch on meta-qt5 ?
One other thing, in the patch link there is an other "stackoverflow" question that is near of my problem and solved by change the "PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"" into "PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_ipk""... That is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

@Khem, I tried to replace my `nativesdk-qtbase_git.bb` by your proposal but that have only created an compatibility error....
Finaly I found a solution that is proposed in the second link that is in the patch [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716949/during-sdk-build-environment-setup-d-conflicts-between-attempted-installs/49003464#49003464). I replace the `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"` by `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_ipk"` in the `local.conf` file.
After that I recompile the toolchain with `bitbacke meta-toolchain-qt5` and that works.
Thank you.